# with cte union all select into

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do the following:

```
with cte as (
select ...
from ....
)

select ... 
from cte

union all

with cte2 as (
select ...
from ....
)

select ... 
into table --
from cte2
```

I could have sworn this worked before but now I am getting an error of `Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "with"`. Is it impossible to write like this or am I missing something else?

I know I can write this as:

```
with cte as (
select ...
from ....
),
with cte2 as (
select ...
from ....
)

select ... 
from cte

union all

select ... 
into table --
from cte2
```

But I am trying not to since data in cte and cte2 come from different partners, so I prefer to keep the `with cte as` and `select from cte` together for each partner.

Comment: You can't use the first method as the "with" of every CTE needs to start with (or more correctly the immediately preceding statement needs to terminate with a semi-colon.  This would require you to terminate after your first Union all.

Comment: @GandRalph any creative way I can re-write this to keep the partner data together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when mutiple CTE you have to remove `with` only `,`.

it looks like :

```
with cte as (
  select 1 id
),cte2 as (
  select 2 id
)
,cte3 as (
  select * from CTE
  union all
  select * from CTE2
)
insert into T select * from CTE3;
```

---

**Result:**

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
```

---

**TEST DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (id int)
;
```

---

**Result:**

```
| ID |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
```

---

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8a355/6/0)

Comment: Got it but as mentioned, I am trying not to do it this way since data in cte and cte2 come from different partners. Trying to keep them together